# Plot with Mathematica

Tags: graphics, export, animation

How Can I plot the following figures for the following equations?

$x\in\mathbb{R}, f(x) = \frac{\left|\sin(x)\right|}{x^2+x+1}$

$t\in\mathbb{R}, A(t)=\displaystyle\int_t^{t+2\pi}\!\dfrac{|\sin    x|}{x^2+x+1}\mathrm{d}x$

[Details of The graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018993/absolute-maximum-of-the-integral/1019140#1019140)

[image]

Comment: I vote that Mark McClure answer this one (see OPs link).

Comment: At least vote him up.

Comment: As Mark's comment on his answer states, the code is given in the answer source. Here it is at the bottom: http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/bdf35e0e-861e-4ecd-ac50-d103850d5411/view-source

Comment: @Rahul, Thanks. I find it and produce it to a gif image.

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_] := Abs@Sin@x/(x x + x  + 1)
a[t_] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, t, t + 2 Pi}]
tabA = Table[{t, a[t]}, {t, -3 Pi, 3 Pi, 6 Pi/100}];
opc = Sequence[ImageSize -> 400,  Ticks -> {Array[- 4 Pi + # Pi &, 6], Automatic}];
Animate[Column[{
   Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -3Pi, 3Pi}, AspectRatio->1/4, Evaluate@opc, PlotRange->{{-3 Pi, 3 Pi}, All}],
        Plot[f[x], {x, tabA[[p, 1]], tabA[[p, 1]] + 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis]],
   Text["area = " <> ToString@N@tabA[[p, 2]]],
   ListLinePlot[tabA, Evaluate@opc, Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, Point[tabA[[p]]]}]}, Center], 
{p, 1, Length@tabA, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: nice. but no control buttons :)

Comment: @Nasser I posted this one only because you were too lazy to note that the Op's model doesn't have buttons :D

Answer (score 2):

It took me few minutes to figure what it is doing. But here is a Manipulate. I did not know the code is there and did not look at original one yet. I am sure it is done better than my attempt here:

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 If[state == "RUN",
  tick = Not[tick];
  a = a + 0.1;
  If[a > 4 Pi,
   state = "RESET";
   a = -4 Pi;
   cArea = {}
   ]
  ];

 Module[{area, g},
  area = NIntegrate[f, {x, a, a + 2 Pi}];
  g = Grid[{{
      Show[
       Plot[f, {x, -4 Pi, 4 Pi},
        PlotRange -> {{-4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {0, .9}}, 
           PlotLabel -> Row[{"Area = ", area}]
        ],

       Plot[f, {x, a, a + 2 Pi}, Filling -> Bottom],

       PlotRange -> {{-4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {0, .9}}, ImageSize -> 400
       ]
      },
     {
      AppendTo[cArea, {a, area}];
      ListPlot[cArea, Joined -> True, 
         PlotRange -> {{-4 Pi, 4 Pi}, {0, 2}},
         Epilog -> Point[{a, area}], 
         Ticks -> {{-4 Pi, -2 Pi, 0, 2 Pi, 4 Pi, 2}, Automatic}]
      }
     }, Frame -> All];
  g
  ],

 Grid[{{Button[Text@Style["run", 12], {state = "RUN"; tick = Not[tick]}, 
      ImageSize -> {60, 40}], 
    Button[Text@Style["stop", 12], {state = "STOP"; tick = Not[tick]}, 
      ImageSize -> {60, 40}], 
    Button[Text@Style["reset", 12], {state = "RESET"; a = -4 Pi;
      cArea = {}; tick = Not[tick]}, ImageSize -> {60, 40}]}}, 
    Spacings -> {.5, 0}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray
  ],

 {{a, -3.99 Pi}, None},
 {{cArea, {}}, None},
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{state, "STOP"}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick},
 SynchronousUpdating -> True,
 Initialization :>
  (
   f = Abs[Sin[x]]/(x^2 + x + 1)
   )
 ]
```